# JSF 2.x Serverside File selection dialog

Tags: jsf-2

With a JSF application, is it possible to show a file selection dialog to the user to select a config file from a specific folder on the server?

Under consideration is a scenario where an application needs to allow the user to select a file to use for a workflow or other process.

I have seen examples of client side File choosers, but haven't come across anything on selecting a file on the server. Is it restricted due to security considerations? Is there a way this could be done?

JSF 2.x

My focus is on ICEFaces at the moment, but would be keen to know if this is doable with any JSF framework.

Comment: Not possible for technical/security reasons, usually get a list of files on server side and propose to select some of them. If you want a tree you can use some tree component...

Comment: Thanks for confirming that @ChristopheRoussy